# as3 URLRequest lost connection - phone App

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, urlrequest

I am using as3 and the Flash Professional IDE to code an app for Droid and IOS. I have noticed a few times when downloading a file nearly 100 megs that it sometimes stops for both android and IOS. It will stay at a certain percentage and I have to close the app to try again.

I am wondering if there is a "BREAK" some how for a moment in the internet connection that the file no longer sees the URL request and just stops. Does this make sense?  Is there a way to fix this?

Here is the line of code I am using. The var urlString comes is an http request. Its a zip file. Exmaple is:

```
var urlString = "http://myWebsite.com/French.zip";
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlString);
```

**UPDATE:** I think I have to add a URLstream to it but still not sure how to do this. I am getting closer I think.

Comment: Why do you need to load 100MB into a Flash Application?

Comment: Good question. It has hundreds of small mp3s in it. They all need to be accessed later. I don't want the user to have to stream them because incase they don't have internet they can use the app anywhere at anytime since the files will be loaded into the app.

Comment: It's a good idea in theory, but I don't think many people would be impressed to find out that your application has used 100MB of their data limit. Maybe you should break the files up into batches? Like 1MB each or something.

Comment: Good thought. Hummm Also they have the option to download folders with multiple content. It will be a one time thing or they will download these folders infrequently. Is there a way to check if the connection has been lost and start over from the same spot?

Comment: Why isn't the data just being included in the application itself?  If it's really required to load all of it it would make more sense to me if it were part of the application that way as a user I could download/update over wifi instead of eating into a cell plan (also no need to wait again after installing the app).

Comment: @shaunhusain, that is a good question too. In short we will be adding multiple languages in folders with content. The users can download "fresh" content often with weekly or monthly new options. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yup I was sort of thinking localization might be the goal or potentially data refresh but thought the latter could just be achieved with application updates.  I haven't written any mobile apps that load this amount of data, but as you said URLStream may be the way to go so you can debug at a low level.

Comment: any idea how to achieve this with urlStream?